# Combine two separate SQL queries in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

```
Name      | Income
----------|----------
Alice     | 200
Bob       | 100
Charlie   | 50
Dave      | 500



Name      | Outcome
----------|----------
Alice     | 300
Bob       | 40
Charlie   | 100
Dave      | 250
```

I can make this query to get all the people who have an income which is greater than 150 and order them

```
SELECT Name, Income
FROM table1
WHERE Income > 150
ORDER BY Income DESC
```

Similarly I can get all the people who have an outcome which is less than 200:

```
SELECT Name, Outcome
FROM table2
WHERE Outcome < 200
ORDER BY Outcome DESC
```

Is there a way to get the two views by writing a single query i.e. using only one `;`?

---

EDIT: I'm sorry, I just realised I wasn't clear about what I want to get. This is more or less what I am trying to achieve:

```
Name      | Income
----------|----------
Dave      | 500
Alice     | 200


Name      | Outcome
----------|----------
Charlie   | 100
Bob       | 40
```

I know about `JOIN` but that would make only one table in a result. I can't use `UNION` either because Outcome and Income do have same datatype but they mean different things.

Comment: What result do you expect? Do you want UNION them or JOIN?

Comment: SELECT table1.Name, table2.Outcome,table1.Income FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.Name =table2.Name WHERE table2.Outcome < 200 and table1.Income>150 ORDER BY table1.Income DESC table2.Outcome DESC

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please show the desired output (and make your example a bit more complicated, e.g. one name not having a match in either table, another having a match in both). If we looked for `income > 300` and `outcome > 200` instead, would you expect two rows for Dave or one row containing both values? If the latter, would you expect `income` to be empty or 200 for Alice's row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are showing is still two separate results. One query gives you one result. If you want to combine the two queries that gives one query and one result. One method:

```
SELECT what, name, value
FROM
(
  SELECT 'INCOME' as what, name, income as value, 1 as sortkey1, -income as sortkey2
  FROM table1
  WHERE income > 150
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'OUTCOME' as what, name, outcome as value, 2 as sortkey1, outcome as sortkey2
  FROM table2
  WHERE outcome < 200
)
ORDER BY sortkey1, sortkey2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` these two tables by Name and `SELECT` both Income and Outcome, e.g.:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.Income, t2.Outcome
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t1.Income > 150 AND t2.Outcome < 200
ORDER BY t1.Income DESC t2.Outcome DESC;
```

**update** (as per edits in question)

You can't have one query resulting on two separate outputs. Closest you can get to it is by using `UNION` with another column to distinguish between the outputs, e.g.:

```
SELECT Name, Income, 'Income'
FROM table1
WHERE Income > 150
ORDER BY Income DESC

UNION

SELECT Name, Outcome, 'Outcome'
FROM table2
WHERE Outcome < 200
ORDER BY Outcome DESC
```

Comment: I know about `JOIN` but the result would be only one table, while what I am trying to achieve is two different tables. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear before, I've just edited the question.